# how to preload or cache destination viewcontroller without instantiate by segue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

When a segue is trigged, it will initiate the destination viewcontroller.  is there a way I can preload or cache the viewcontroller and load it in code when the segue is trigged?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One of the benefits of using segues is that the view controllers is setup and instantiated for you. You can simply not use segues, and init/push your VC onto the navigation stack yourself. This will allow you to initialize it whenever you want, store the VC as an ivar, then push it when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. e.g. for better responsiveness I had the need to preload photos that is shown when the device is rotated. So in the storyboard, I selected the landscape VC and set the Storyboard ID in the Identity Inspector. Then when the portrait VC loaded I created the landscape VC by calling:

```
self.landscapeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"landscapePhotosVC"];
// this next line is critical so photos can be added to the UIScrollView. 
// Else the UIScrollView on landscape VC will be nil
[self.landscapeViewController view];
self.landscapeViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
self.landscapeViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
```

Then when viewDidAppear fires on the portrait VC, I add the photos to the UIScrollView on landscape VC.

When the device rotates to landscape I show the landscape VC:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:self.landscapeViewController 
                                        animated:YES 
                                      completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can instantiate view controller without segue, set storyboardID for UIViewController in storyboard editor first, then access it with

```
MyViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyVC"];
```